# Can a Microsoft Bot Framework based bot be connected to multiple channels?

Tags: c#, node.js, botframework

So i have inspected multiple examples now, but i have yet to see a chat bot that is connected to say facebook and skype, not just one of them, if it is the case that your bot can be connected to multiple channels, is there a way in the code to distinguish from which channel the message is coming from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. The way to do it is by checking the ChannelId of the incoming message in C# or the source in the case of Node.

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-ReceiveAttachment/ReceiveAttachmentDialog.cs#L30) is a C# example.

```
if (message.ChannelId.Equals("skype", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) 
{
...
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/Node/core-ReceiveAttachment/app.js#L71) is a Node.js example.

```
var isSkypeMessage = function (message) {
    return message.source === 'skype';
};
```